# Select all orders where order_item meta key and value equals something

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to get a list of specific orders based on a selected product variation attribute.
This is the SQL equivalent of what I'm trying to do in PHP with the Woocommerce functions:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta 
ON wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id 
WHERE wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = "size" AND wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value = "A2"
```

(well, not exactly, because I want to retrieve a list with each full order object for the matching meta data but you get the idea).

The SQL query returns the following results:
[image]

Based on the [documentation found here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query#adding-custom-parameter-support) I translated this into the following PHP code:

```
/**
 * Handle a custom 'customvar' query var to get orders with the 'customvar' meta.
 * @param array $query - Args for WP_Query.
 * @param array $query_vars - Query vars from WC_Order_Query.
 * @return array modified $query
 */
function handle_custom_query_var( $query, $query_vars ) {
    if ( ! empty( $query_vars['size'] ) ) {
        $query['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'size',
            'value' => esc_attr( $query_vars['size'] ),
        );
    }

    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query', 'handle_custom_query_var', 10, 2 );

function woocommerce_orders_export()
{
    $orders = wc_get_orders(array('size' => 'A2'));
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something. The result of the above code is an empty array (`var_dump($orders);` returns `array(0){}`)

**UPDATE**

I've made the following temporary solution for now:

```
function get_orders_by_meta_key_value( $meta_key, $meta_value ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Get order item IDs based on meta_key and meta_value
    $order_item_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "
    SELECT order_item_id
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta
    WHERE meta_key = '{$meta_key}'
    AND meta_value = '{$meta_value}'
  " );

    // Get order IDs based on order_item_ids
    $order_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "
    SELECT DISTINCT order_id
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items
    WHERE order_item_id IN (" . implode( ',', $order_item_ids ) . ")
  " );

    // Get orders based on order_ids
    $orders = array();
    foreach ( $order_ids as $order_id ) {
        $orders[] = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    }

    return $orders;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more fast and better solution.

Create function that will get all orders by parameter

```
function get_orders_by_size($size) {
  global $wpdb;
  $table_prefix = $wpdb->prefix;

  $query = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM {$table_prefix}woocommerce_order_items oi 
    LEFT JOIN {$table_prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta oim 
    ON oi.order_item_id = oim.order_item_id 
    WHERE oim.meta_key = 'size' 
    AND oim.meta_value = %s
  ";

  $results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($query, $size));

  return $results;
}
```

To use it:

```
$results = get_orders_by_size('A2');

foreach ($results as $result) {
  // Do something with each order item
}
```

Here is a solution with the filter you tried

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query', 'custom_get_orders_by_size', 10, 2 );

function custom_get_orders_by_size( $args, $query_vars ) {
  global $wpdb;

  $table_prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
  $meta_key = 'size';
  $meta_value = 'A2';

  $args['join'] .= " LEFT JOIN {$table_prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS oim ON oim.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id";
  $args['where'] .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND oim.meta_key = %s AND oim.meta_value = %s", $meta_key, $meta_value );

  return $args;
}
```

Comment: My temporary solution comes very close to this. See my current solution in the updated question.